# Net core 2.0 error running Web Api "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]"

Tags: console, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0

I am doing an `Net Core 2.0 Application`. I have several `Web Api Projects` that I started from Command Line..

`c:\debug directore\dotnet prj.dll`

It starts the service on ports indicating on Program file

```html
 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback,5000);
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001);
        })
        .Build();
```

It appears this screen

```html
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\l0658073\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Debug\netcoreapp2.0
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:5000
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:5001
```

And everything was working fine

But suddenly it stopped working correctly.... When i run the projects

It only appears

```html
PS C:\Debug\netcoreapp2.0> dotnet INOMSmartrouting.dll
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\l0658073\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
```

the ports does not appear.

I see in `task Manager`, and each process use 25% por the memory.

What has happend? What I am missing?

Thanks